# React input color picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand, how the input color type works.

I am trying to have a color picker and put the value into a state variable "color".

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(false);
const colorPicker = () => {
    console.log("colorPicker", color.target);
    return(
        <input type="color" value={color} onChange={setColor}/>
    );
}
```

But this gives me just a flood of javascript objects in the console and when I try to look into for instance color.target it throws an error:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must
>   keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See
>   https:// fb  dot me/react-event-pooling for more information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `onChange` event handler receives an event object as parameter.

This event object contains the selected color as `event.target.value`, just like a regular text input would.

---

With this in mind, the following will allow you to hold on to the selected color:

```
const ColorPicker = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(null);

  console.log("colorPicker", color);

  return (
    <input type="color" value={color} onChange={e => setColor(e.target.value)} />
  );
}
```

---

Regarding the error you see when you try to access `event.target`, the error message already does a good job explaining it. I suggest you take a look at the documentation page it refers to, that should help you understand the problem.

Comment: Cool thx! It it normal if setColor closes the dialog right after the user click? If setColor is removed, the dialog can let the user hold click, drag on to choose before the color is selected.